# orTools how to get status from RoutingModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, or-tools

I'm setting time limit on routingModel with the code below.

```
RoutingSearchParameters search_parameters = RoutingModel.DefaultSearchParameters();
search_parameters.FirstSolutionStrategy = FirstSolutionStrategy.Types.Value.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC;
search_parameters.TimeLimitMs = 30000;
RoutingModel routing = new RoutingModel(number_of_locations, number_of_vehicles);
```

But I don't know how to get status after the search is completed so I can check if it was time limit that canceled it or solution has NOT been found because of other reasons. Please help

```
Assignment solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters);
```

RoutingModel class has this static properties but I don't know how to read them from the instance:

```
public static readonly int ROUTING_FAIL;
public static readonly int ROUTING_FAIL_TIMEOUT;
public static readonly int ROUTING_INVALID;
public static readonly int ROUTING_NOT_SOLVED;
public static readonly int ROUTING_SUCCESS;
```

Answer (score 0):

> ..it was time limit that canceled it or solution has been found..

This works for me in python 3:

```
....
solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

if solution:
    print("Solution Found")
    ....
else:
    print("Terminated without finding solution")
```

Its not clear from the question if you are looking for the above solution or you are are you interested in checking if the solution found is optimal.

Comment: Hi NFern, thanks for responding. I'm made an error in answer where I typed "it was time limit that canceled it or solution has been found..." I meant to type "it was time limit that canceled it or solution has NOT been found because of other reasons." I wanna know if time limit is the reason that solution hasn't been found.